# Can't build a value of type Vec<B> from an iterator over elements of type Vec<B>

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct A {
    pub a: Vec<B>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct B {
    pub b: Vec<C>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct C {
    pub c: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let c = C { c: 1 };
    let b = B { b: vec![c] };
    let a = A { a: vec![b] };
    let va = vec![a];
    let ret = va.iter().map(|x| x.a.clone()).collect::<Vec<B>>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=980cabe1a7d7decd54f20d576d9e47d3)

This code produces this error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<B>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `Vec<B>`
  --> src/main.rs:20:44
   |
20 |     let ret=va.iter().map(|x| x.a.clone()).collect::<Vec<B>>();;
   |                                            ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<B>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=Vec<B>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<Vec<B>>` is not implemented for `Vec<B>`
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
```

I don't understand.
The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E) say that `Vec<T>` implements `FromIterator` without condition on T.

Comment: `va.iter().map(|x| x.a.clone())` is an iterator over `Vec<B>`s, so when you collect it you will get a vector of `Vec<B>`s (or in other words, a `Vec<Vec<B>>`). Perhaps you wanted to use the [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means the element yielded from the iterator is of `Vec<B>` and therefore cannot be collected to form a list of `Vec<B>`.

It can be fixed by either changing the target type to `Vec<Vec<B>>`:

```
let ret=va.iter().map(|x| x.a.clone()).collect::<Vec<Vec<B>>>();
```

Or flattening the elements:

```
let ret=va.iter().flat_map(|x| x.a.clone()).collect::<Vec<B>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b98454095f76b8d831da304220639777)